# Can a comma be used to REPLACE a subordinating conjunction?

Tags: grammar, phrases, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences, participial

I am aware that the formulas for complex sentences are ID and D,I (I=independent and D=dependent), but I have a sentence that has an I and D but adding a subordinate conjunction sounds weird.
"He woke from the best sleep of his life, feeling well rested"
As you can see, this is and I,D (which is wrong). However, all I did was add a comma where the subordinate conjunction was supposed to be. Is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

As rightly explained by Brian, "feeling well rested" is a phrase. A phrase is a group of words giving incomplete meaning. Phrases are to be viewd from the point of construction as well as from that of function.In your phrase--   feeling well rested-- 'feeling' is a particple(partly verb + partly adjective).

Your phrase is a participle phrase by construction and adjective phrase by function qualifying the pronoun "he". You can put this phrase in the beginning or at the end and with a"," as proposed.

In the beginning the functioning as adjective becomes all. the more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not see it that way.  I think you're focusing so much on independent and dependent clauses that you perceive everything as one or the other.

This is not true.

", feeling well rested" is not a clause. It is an adverbial phrase, modifying "woke. It tells _how_he woke.

That's all there is to it.  Nothing about I vs. D clauses.

Comment: I'd call it an adjectival phrase modifying the subject -- a 'secondary predication'. But I think you hit the nail on the head in the rest of it.

Comment: That made me facepalm really hard. I completely forgot about phrases at the moment lol